# When call ends open application to show details about call duration

Tags: iphone, call

I am new in iPhone application development. Now I am developing a call history application. I want my application to run in background and when the call is finished the application show call details. I don't know how to develop this. Please help me any one know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there is no way to do what you want using the iOS SDK. The user's call history is private.